# Markov Channel Attribution - Removal removal_effort formula for conversion amount

Tags: google-analytics, markov-chains, markov

For below sample data Python Package "Channel Attribution" generating removal effort values as [OutPut:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cmvF.png)
What formula is used to calculate removal effort for conversion amount?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtbYW.png)

I understand Removal Effort for Conversion is calculated using : 1- (Conversion without channel)/(Overall Conversion)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.